# Iterate through two layers of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am trying to iterate through an NSDictionary from a serialized JSON file. The dictionary has two levels and I cannot seem to access the second layer properly.

I am wondering if there is a way to increment an objectForKey such as:

```
for (id key in [itemList allKeys]) {
        [objectivesArray addObject:[[itemList objectForKey:@"Example0"] objectForKey:@"Objective"]];
    }
```

My keys in the Dictionary (second level) are like, Example0, Example1, Example2.

UPDATE:

The desired output would be arrays for each of the values contained within the top level keys. The JSON basically looks like this:
Top Level

```
  Example1
    Key1: Value1
    Key2: Value2
  Example2
    Key1: Value1
    Key2: Value2
```

and so on. I have tried nesting For loops to get the Key and values:

```
for (id key in [itemList allKeys]) {
  id value = [itemList objectForKey:key]; 
  Value = [value objectForKey:@"Example1"];
   firstLevelDictionary = [itemList objectForKey:key];

        for (id key2 in firstLevelDictionary) {
             NSLog(@"%@", [firstLevelDictionary objectForKey:@"Key1"]);
             [keyArray addObject:[firstLevelDictionary objectForKey:@"Key1"]];
       }
    }
```

etc.

Now, I can access them when I manually write them all out:

```
[key1Array addObject:[[itemList objectForKey:@"Key1"] objectForKey:@"Value1"]];
[key2Array addObject:[[itemList objectForKey:@"Key2"] objectForKey:@"Value2"]];
```

But that is obviously not at all what I want. So I'm wondering if there's a way to do nested loops by incrementing an integer contained within the objectForKey key value.

UPDATE 2: this is the JSON format Im working with, I put baseball terms in place of data for now:
{
      "Situ0":{
         "Situation":"Tying Runner on 1st",
         "Bases":[
            1
         ],
         "Outs":0,
         "Score":[
            1,
            2
         ],
         "Purpose":"Sac Bunt",
         "Objective":"Bunt"
      },
      "Situ1":{
         "Situation":"Tying Runner On 2nd",
         "Bases":[
            2
         ],
         "Outs":1,
         "Score":[
            1,
            2
         ],
         "Purpose":"Score / Move Runner Over",
         "Objective":"Hit Behind Runner / Hit"
      }

Comment: You will probably need a nested `for` loop, but you need to more clearly explain the structure of the dictionary and the desired output

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question to include a sample of the NSDictionary you are trying to iterate.

Comment: The dictionary is from the JSON value I referenced in the question.

Comment: So you want an array for each top-level dictionary entry, containing the values from that dictionary.  Do you want these arrays in an array or a dictionary?  If a dictionary, what should the key be?

Comment: I want an array for each top level entry, as well as a dictionary for each sub dictionary key/value pair. The keys can be either 0-based numbers or specific keys that I have in the original JSON file

Comment: So you just want to covert the outer dictionary to an array of dictionaries?

Comment: right, but the second part of the question is: how can I iterate through, but increment my objectForKey? As Example1 is the first element, Im also asking how would you also get the objectForKey for Example2, Example3 etc.?

Comment: When you log to the console, like NSLog(@"This is an element: %@", Element1), I am wondering if that sort of thing is possible outside of logging? The "%@" part, I mean. I am not sure what that is called... format specifier? %@ - object, %d integer, etc... because I want to be able to make an array of each inner dictionary key, as well.

Comment: Well, you could construct a string using stringformatting and an int but generally you would just iterate over the `keys` of a dictionary with a `for in` loop

Comment: I think you are struggling because you are trying to put the values into discrete arrays; `key1Array`, `key2Array` etc.  This will be difficult.  You need to put your arrays into a single array, then you can just use a loop.  You will have an array of arrays of dictionary or something. It would help if you could update your question with the JSON notation of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: The reason I wanted discreet arrays is because the different Examples correspond. In other words, Example1 contains two Keys that must be retained, and Example2 has specific info that must be retained in that array, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help you to iterate the second layer of `NSDictionary`:

```
- (void)iterateSecondLayerOfDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {

    for (id subDictKey in dict.allKeys) {

        NSDictionary *subDict = [dict objectForKey:subDictKey];

        for (id valueKey in subDict.allKeys) {

            NSString *value = [subDict objectForKey:valueKey];

            NSLog(@"%@", value);

        }
    }
}
```

To test, here is some example data:

```
NSDictionary *subDict = @{ @"key1": @"value1",
                           @"key2": @"value2",
                           @"key3": @"value3",
                           @"key4": @"value4"
                         };

NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"Example0": subDict,
                        @"Example1": subDict,
                        @"Example2": subDict
                      };

NSLog(@"%@", dict);
[self iterateSecondLayerOfDictionary:dict];
```

Output:

```
//This is your actual data
{
  Example0 = {
               key1 = value1;
               key2 = value2;
               key3 = value3;
               key4 = value4;
              };
  Example1 = {
               key1 = value1;
               key2 = value2;
               key3 = value3;
               key4 = value4;
              };
  Example2 = {
               key1 = value1;
               key2 = value2;
               key3 = value3;
               key4 = value4;
              };
}

//These are the values you are trying to access. Though the orders aren't guaranteed as they are NSDictionaries
value3
value2
value1
value4
value3
value4
value2
value1
value3
value2
value1
value4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need. But I highly recommend **don't** follow this method.

Tip: Instead of keeping `subDict` in another dictionary try to get it inside an Array (from api). Then you can easily get it by `NSArray * key1Array = [array valueForKey:@"key1"];`

```
    NSDictionary *subDict = @{ @"key0": @"value0",
                               @"key1": @"value1",
                               @"key2": @"value2",
                               };

    NSDictionary *dict = @{ @"Example0": subDict,
                            @"Example1": subDict,
                            @"Example2": subDict
                            };

    NSMutableDictionary *keyValues = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (int i =0; i < dict.count; i ++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Example%d",i];
        NSDictionary *innerDic = [dict valueForKey:key];
        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
        NSString *innerKey ;
        for (int j = 0; j < innerDic.count; j ++) {
            innerKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d",i];
            NSString *value = [innerDic valueForKey:innerKey];
            [array addObject:value];
        }
        [keyValues setObject:array forKey:innerKey];
    }
    NSLog(@"KEY VALUES: %@", keyValues);
```

By this you can get `key1Array` by

```
key1Array = [keyValues valueForKey: @"key1"];
```

Comment: Why don't you recommend going that route?

Comment: Instead of keeping subDict in another dictionary try to get it inside an Array (from api). Then you can easily get it by NSArray * key1Array = [array valueForKey:@"key1"];

Comment: It creates NSMutableDictionary, NSMutableArray & Nested for-loops